# how to create java array while passing an argument?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there better way to do this?

```
HashMap<String, String[]> SddcWithViolations = null;

String[] str1 = { str[1], str[2] } ;

SddcWithViolations.put(str[0], str1 );
```

Comment: This won't compile + throw NPE so yes there is better way to do :D

Comment: it would throw runtime exception!

Comment: Well other than this just... not compiling at all (you are calling put on a null-reference) the question is what would a "better" way improve? Performance? Readability? Number of bytes? What is better for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the instance, otherwies you'll get `NPE`. Also use `Map` interface which provides extra methods. Try this:

```
Map<String, String[]> sddcWithViolations = new HashMap<>();;

    String[] str1 = { str[1], str[2] } ;

    sddcWithViolations.put(str[0], str1 );
```

But I don't see any need of `Map` here. `List` is fine.

```
Arrays.asList(str1);
```

Comment: `new String[]{str[1], str[2]}`

Comment: what do you mean ? what's the problem here?

Comment: ohhh.. I'll assume there's another array like String str[] = {....} This is assumed obviously

Answer (score 0):

You may initialize and put values to the Map in one statement using anonymous class.

```
    String[] str = {"one", "two", "three"};
    Map<String, String[]> SddcWithViolations = new HashMap<String, String[]>(){{
        put(str[0], new String[]{str[1], str[2]});
    }};

    SddcWithViolations.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " => " + Arrays.asList(value)));
```

Outputs:

> one => [two, three]